# Discussion based questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Well this question is bound to be controversial. What should we do?

[What is being done to make the academic environment more women friendly?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2113/319)

Answer (score 5):

I think a subtly changing the question from what "CAN" be done to what "IS" being done might make it less "discussion" oriented without changing the meaning too much.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to (the second part is the "IS")

Answer (score 2):

My feeling (mentioned in comments) is that the second part of the question (asking for references to work studying this issue) is legitimate and concrete. The first part involves discussion and so is not well suited. This also eliminates the need to discuss "why" one should care about the issue - I personally think that's troll bait, but there's no point arguing it on the forum itself.